# Apple Mail Archive

Tags: mail.app, email

If I move E-Mails to archive in apple mail will they still also be on the server?

Or will they only be on my computer then where the archive is?

Comment: Which email provider (iCloud, gmail, hotmail, yahoo, or your own domain) do you use?

Comment: they will be in the archive folder of the email servers

Comment: @pjctech iCloud, gmail and more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a email server that uses the IMAP protocol or Exchange all your emails and folders will be saved on the server.

iCloud.com, Gmail.com, Outlook.com use either exchange or IMAP.
If you have your own email server, you should connect to it through IMAP.

**IMAP:**

> IMAP was designed with the goal of permitting complete management of an
>   email box by multiple email clients, therefore clients generally leave
>   messages on the server until the user explicitly deletes them.

Comment: I was actually after the export button, which does what I need :) but you answered the question, thank you!

Comment: I assumed you meant the archive button and folder.

Answer (score 0):

Export function doesn't remove the mail from the server, just makes an independent offline copy of your mails. thus, your mails are not going to be removed. they will still stay with your server, and a copy is downloaded for entirely independent access.